# Adding Subtype to generic List

Tags: java, generics, exception, stream, sax

I am trying to add exception to a Map containing string as key and List of exceptions as values..as shown below.
What I am trying to achieve is to create a generic method that can accept a Map with  key as String and a list that can contain any type of exception ,if the key is of the same type add the exception to that particular List.

```
public static void addToMap(Map<String,List<? extends Exception>> exceptionMap,String nodeKey ,Exception exception){
exceptionMap.computeIfAbsent(nodeKey ,K->new LinkedList<Exception>).add(exception);
```

Note: I can add the exceptions to two different util methods seperately ...but i want it to be more generic a single util  method as shown above...

I am unable to add these two different excpetions to generic util method,i dont know where i am going wrong...Any Help is Kinldly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use wildcards here. Use wildcards only when you don't care about the exact type. But here, you *do* care about the exact type of list of exceptions. Namely, these two `???` must be compatible with each other:

```
void addToExceptionMap(Map<String, List<???>> exceptionMap, String errorLevel, ??? exception)
```

The last parameter can't be just any `Exception`, and the type of list can't just be any `Exception`. You can't add a `NullPointerException` to a list of `IndexOutOfRangeExceptions`, can you? These two types are related.

You should use a generic here:

```
public static <T extends Exception> void addToExceptionMap(Map<String, List<T>> exceptionMap, String errorLevel, T exception){
    exceptionMap.computeIfAbsent(errorLevel,K->new LinkedList<T>()).add(exception);
}
```